# Want to knw the UML diagram of the given use case

Tags: uml

Below is my use case scenario please help me in creating UML diagram:

1 Enter the data in the given input filed.
2 ‘Save’ button
3 Once the user clicks on the save button the system need to check the given details are already available in the existing database. If not then the given values need to be saved on to the database and the system have to display a success message.
4 Once the data is successfully inserted display the same data in the grid below.
5 If the given details already exists in the database then the system need to display  a        message to the user.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Basically its a flow and mostly we will use below umls for that.

Activity Diagram/Flow Chart

Sequence diagram

Comment: I have this use case and i want to create UML for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

in your system you can add following basic use cases
1:Insert the data
2:Check validation of the data
3:Update the data
4:Return Error

and actors are
1.user
2.may be u can add an admin actor for controlling the system

Comment: Ok can you give an example for it..@shriram